# date and hwclock is out of sync after every reboot

Tags: 14.04, server, clock

I have searched previous questions but unfortunately did not solve my problem therefore I wanted to ask.
I checked bios time, it is set to my localtime zone (gmt+3)

But in ubuntu things are different here's a sample output of date and hwclock

```
$ date
Sun Oct 30 14:12:12 +03 2016
$ sudo hwclock
Sun 30 Oct 2016 11:12:14 AM +03  -0.223741 seconds
```

Problem is, I use rtcwake commands often. I used to set rtcwake stuff but nowadays Ubuntu is acting out and it's setting rtcwake via hwclock, which you can see it's 3 hours behind comparing to what my time is. It says +3 but it's not affective, just seemed to me cosmetics.

Looking for help thanks.